# Capybara Selenium webdriver Transactional Rollbacks work arounds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, integration-testing

I'm writing a couple of Feature Specs for an app and using the default Selenium webdriver that comes with Capybara. This is the spec I have written.

```
DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      find(:css,'.dropdown-toggle').click
      click_on "Locations"  
      find(:css, "#location-8-upgradesub-60").click 
      value1 = find(:css, "#location-8-review-subscription").text
      value1.should be == '(2) Reviews (Paid)'    
end
```

I'm facing 2 issues with this snippet:

1) Capybara isn't waiting for the XHR to get over and is coming out of the test before that. It works if I give a sleep condition for about 10 sec.

**UPDATE**
Solved 1) by setting Capybara.default_wait_time = 15 and writing a helper to make sure jQuery isn't active. `page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?`

2) I'm not able to rollback the DB transaction that takes place when selenim simulates the test. I see an `INSERT` and `COMMIT` in the `test.log` but no `ROLLBACK` because of which I need to keep changing my specs every time I run the test. If I use,`DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation`, my entire DB gets wiped out and that is not something I want.

I've done some extensive googling on this issue and haven't been able to find an efficient work around. I've tried using the same transactional thread too, for the test server. Haven't had fruitful results with too! Any heads up or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I followed this link https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions and put my spec inside a `before(:each)` block and stored the value in an `@value1` instance variable to compare it with the desired value within the `it` block. I haven't had any luck with that too.

```
before(:each) do
  find(:css,'.dropdown-toggle').click
  click_on "Locations"
  find(:css, "#location-8-upgradesub-60").click
  wait_for_ajax #Helper method to wait for ajax call to get over 
  find(:css, "#location-8-review-subscription").should be_visible
  @value1 = find(:css, "#location-8-review-subscription").text
end

it "should open the dropdown, find Location and open it's modal", js:true do
    @value1.should be == '(2) Reviews (Paid)'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a work around. I added this code snippet in `spec_helper.rb`. Not using Database Cleaner anymore.

*Reference*: http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/#comment-441060846. The entire comment thread is pretty useful.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.class_eval do
  def current_connection_id
    # Thread.current.object_id
    Thread.main.object_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With 1), I think have_content or have_selector will work. These methods will wait for some seconds before checking the content/selector exist. You could config this time via spec_helper.rb. You could put have_content/have_selector BEFORE your find(..).click to make sure it is exist before next tests.

Comment: That didn't work either. The `#location-8-review-subscription` is loaded inside a Bootstrap Modal once I click a button and the `page` object doesn't seem to pick up content from the modal. I tweaked the default wait time to 15 sec using `Capybara.default_wait_time = 15`.

Comment: You already tried with page.should have_selector(...) & it did not work ?

Comment: Yup. I solved the first issue. I did a `find(..).should be_visible`. It seems to solve the first issue. The second issue is what is consuming all my time. :(

Comment: It was weird. I think ".should" should fix the issue, because it added a wait. "have_selector" & "be visible" might works similarly in this content... Anyway, I could learn from your way  :)